# How to display SVN build iteration on a webpage?

Tags: php, svn

We're building a PHP site and are using a SVN system to track changes. Is there a dynamic simple way of displaying the "version" / "revision" of the code changes directly in the html generated by our php script?

That way, our test users can identify what version is present on their system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [svn keywords](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) like `$Revision$` to show this information.

Comment: +1 Just beware that this will only work if the file was modified (such as a change log)...  The only other alternative (that I know) is to use a post-commit hook...

Comment: Anything which shows the "overall" build version/revision? I want to show one common value across the website on each page...

Comment: Thanks tangens - good enough for the time being, but am looking for an "overall" build version...